# elasticsearch data: denormalizing and faceted search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a number items of clothing (jeans, shirts, dresses, socks) each of which comes in many colors (green, red, blue, black).

Does it make sense to have two elasticsearch indexes (one on clothing type and one on clothing color)?  And if so, how do I reference both when someone queries for shirts in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case, its makes no sense to have two seperate indexes. Elasticsearch supports now [joining queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) and [parent child](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html) relations, but it comes with a cost of performance.

Comment: Your point is well taken -  I am investigating parent-child to see if it makes more sense.